# Do I have to create database in SQLite too or using mysql in xampp makes my job while working in android studio

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, android-studio

Do I have to create database in SQLite too or using mysql in xampp makes my job while working in  android studio.
Am also planning to have a web app which will be built using php and mysql.
So please help me to know whether it is necessary to create database in mysql and also in SQLite.
Please Help me.
Am new to android app development

Comment: Try reading the documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html.

Comment: Use SQLite as local storage in Android and MySQL in web server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app works on internet only then you don't need SQLite database. but if you want offline working of app you have to use SQLite Database. SQLite Database is static database using single device. So when internet is not available you can access your data from local SQLite Database. Hope this helps you. If you need further detail feel free to ask :) :) Happy to help you :)

Comment: If this helps you mark this as a correct answer so other getting help from this. Happy to help you @sheetalgowda :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to create local database.If you want to store some then need to create SQLite Database.